# I cannot import tensorflow , please help me to resolve it

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- 
  packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
  from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code 3221225501


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

​#this is shown when i was gonna import it.I also tried to download visual c++ but now it showing.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read this? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35598
It seems like your CPU does not support avx instruction sets. Whats your CPU?